# RenderBody doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a main layout in which @Renderbody does work, but I'm working on a new controller (called System) now so I wanted to use another lay-out. So I added `_ViewStart.cshtml` inside the `~/Views/System` folder. The content of this page is:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_System.cshtml";
}
```

So I've made a view inside the Shared views folder called `_System.cshtml`. It does seem to find the layout, because when I removed _System.cshtml it did say there was no layout.

But why does it give this error? :\

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

Source Error:

Line 11:         <div id="content">
Line 12:             @RenderBody
Line 13:         </div>
Line 14:     </body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RenderBody` is a method:

```
@RenderBody()
```